# Spring integration wire tap a slack notification

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

For the application that I'm building, I need to be able to send slack messages indicating the progress and success/failure of the processed file.

I didn't found a totally straightforward way of doing it, so I'm doing the following:

Declare a queue channel to receive the messages that need to be sent

```
@Bean
MessageChannel slackChannel() {
  return MessageChannels.queue(SLACK_CHANNEL).get();
}
```

Every message sent to that channel is going to be sent as a Slack message. To push messages there, I'm doing a wireTap like:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow startFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows
         ...
         .wireTap(sendSlack("A nice message describing what's happening")
         ...
}

private IntegrationFlow sendSlack(String message) {
    return sf -> sf
            .transform(Message.class, m -> MessageBuilder.createMessage(message, m.getHeaders()))
            .channel(SLACK_CHANNEL);
}
```

And lastly, the slack flow:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow slackFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows.from(SLACK_CHANNEL)
            .handle(slackService, "send")
            .get();
}
```

The class `SlackService` has all the logic to send the message. I like this approach because I could send messages to the slack channel from different places and be handled in the same way, but I'm not sure if it's ok to have the private method `sendSlack` returning an IntegrationFlow and also having the bean that is subscribed to the channel. Will it be better to simplify to?

```
private IntegrationFlow sendSlack(String message) {
    return sf -> sf
            .transform(Message.class, m -> MessageBuilder.createMessage(message, m.getHeaders()))
            .handle(slackService, "send");
}
```

I do not need the queue channel with this option, but I'm not sure if proper use of the wireTap.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not the way to use wire-tap as it is designed. See docs:
https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/WireTap.html

> How do you inspect messages that travel on a point-to-point channel?

According to your current configuration you just ignore an original message published to that wire-tap, but rather you create your own as an arg for that `sendSlack()` factory method. Which, essentially is just a static value, so pointless to have such a complex and distributed logic just to send a static string. (I may be wrong at this point and your message to slack is not so static as it is in that code snippet in the question...)

You may consider to use a `@MessagingGateway` as a contract to distinguish and tunnel the business logic: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway